Can the concept of angular velocity be uniquely defined for a deforming rigid body in non-uniform motion?
In rigid body mechanics, angular velocity is well-defined when the body maintains its rigidity. However, consider the case of a body that is deforming due to external forces while simultaneously undergoing complex translational and rotational motion. For instance:
A spinning asteroid in space that deforms due to internal stress or tidal forces.
A fluid-filled satellite with deformable walls subjected to external torques and gravitational gradients.
Specific Questions:

Is it possible to uniquely define an angular velocity vector for such a body at every instant, despite the deformation?

How do the equations of motion adapt to account for both the deformation and the non-uniform rotation?

Can we use principal axes or a generalized moment of inertia tensor to describe such a system, and if so, how would they evolve over time?

Is there a physical limit to the deformation at which angular velocity as a concept becomes meaningless?



I'm taking a stab at the answer here, would appreciate suggestions!

We define the angular velocity of a rigid body by finding the instantaneous axis of rotation (IAOR) from the instantaneous center of rotation (ICOR) and then calculate the instantaneous angular displacement rate $\vec{\omega} = \frac{\vec{d\theta}}{dt}$ around that axis (We can always find an IAOR for a rigid body, proof here). By definition, the rigid body only rotates around the IAOR (so same angular displacement $\vec{d\theta}$ for all particles), because there is no relative motion between particles in a rigid body. In a deforming body, such an axis is not possible, because there can always be relative motion between particles as the body deforms, so different particles can have different $\vec{d\theta}$. In this case, you can define local $\vec{\omega}$ for subsections about their own axes of rotation, but not a single unique $\vec{\omega}$ for the whole body.
The total body would still follow the same motion as its COM, since forces that deform a body are applied in equal magnitude and opposite in direction.  If you want details of the internal motions, we can write (total motion = motions of the COM + motions about the COM). Equations of motion are always valid in their instantaneous forms, $\vec{L} = \int \vec{r}\times(\vec{v}dm) = \int \vec{r}(t)\times\vec{v}(\vec{r},t)\rho(\vec{r},t)d^3r$ and $\vec{\tau} = \frac{d\vec{L}}{dt}$ which you will have to apply to every subsection you defined from the previous point and obtain COM motions for those subsections first, then relate the combined motions of all subsection COM's with respect to the body's COM. Note however, that not all the $\vec{L}, \vec{\tau}$ are independent and are constrained by the constitutive equations of your body (to prevent tearing) and Newton's laws.
From point 1, I don't see the utility of finding a moment of inertia for the whole body. You could follow the process here if you wish.
Points cannot rotate, so in the limiting case of point-like geometry, angular velocity is not defined.

I think you'll notice the serious difficulties in applying such a general mechanical model to any dynamics analysis, so typically you would try to approximate the deformations as being slower than your motion time scale, decouple motion and deformation and argue that your body, therefore, undergoes shape changes and rigid motion self-consistently every instant.
